# Syntax error on token "else" — how on earth?

Tags: java, karel

I'm learning Java the classic way — by playing around with Karel.

But I seem to have encountered a simple problem I can't solve even with the help of Google.

I'm getting an error in Eclipse saying there's a syntax error on the token "else", and that I should delete it.

How come? The syntax in the code block above the else statement is identical.

Here's my code:

```
public void run() {

    putBeeper();
    if(beepersPresent()){

        move();

    } while(frontIsClear()){
        move();
        putBeeper();
    } else if(facingEast()){

        turnLeft();
        move();

    }
        }
```

Comment: Wow people, do we really need 8 responses saying the same thing?

Comment: @Skynorth To be fair to the answerers, 7 of 8 of them answered within the same minute, with the 8th not far behind.

Comment: I usually delete or cancel my answer when there's a *better* duplicate been posted at the same time: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15775/do-you-delete-your-own-answer-when-its-a-duplicate Most others also do that. It keeps the noise down.

Answer (score 4):

The `else` statement has to follow immediatly after the `if`, you have a `while` loop between them.

Since this was downvoted, more formal the relevant section of [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html)

> 14.9 The if Statement The if statement allows conditional execution of a statement or a conditional choice of two statements, executing one
>   or the other but not both.

```
IfThenStatement:
        if ( Expression ) Statement

IfThenElseStatement:
        if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else Statement

IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf:
        if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else StatementNoShortIf
```

The Expression must have type boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're trying to say `while() { } else {`

Why else?

(Yes, I did just do that.)

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` matches `while`, not `if`. Not entirely clear what you are trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

Probably:

```
while(frontIsClear())
```

should be

```
else if(frontIsClear())
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do here?

```
while(frontIsClear()){
        move();
        putBeeper();
    } else if(facingEast()){

        turnLeft();
        move();
```

While this.. else if that? Not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You put your `else` after a `while`, this is indeed a syntax error

Try that:

```
public void run() {
    putBeeper();
    if(beepersPresent()){
        move();
    } 
    while(frontIsClear()){
        if (facingEast()) {
            turnLeft();
        }
        move();
        putBeeper();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really quite simple.

Your if lasts between the { and }. The else has to be exactly afterwards.

Remove the } near the while and put it somewhere else and you should be ok.